# Launch bootstrap modal when page loads with parameters

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

How to load bootstrap modal when page loads and include the parameters. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#userModal').modal('show', function() {
      var name = 'brian';
      var user_id = 366; 
      $('#userModal .userName').val(name);
      $('#userModal .userId').val(user_id); 
  });
});
```

The result: modal can display when load page directly but it doesn't pass parameter for `name` and `user_id`

The goal is: when page loads, modal display and it can pass the parameter `name` and `user_id`

Comment: Try first set `$().on('shown.bs.modal', /* your function */)` and then `$().modal('show')`. Where you found that second argument is accepted?

Comment: You need to hook into the `shown.bs.modal` event - there's no callback as a 2nd argument.  See first example here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: thank you!! @Justinas it works...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call

```
 $('#userModal').modal('show', function() {
```

is trying to do something similar to `$.ajax` functions (like `$.load`), ie:

```
 $(selector).modal(action, callback)
```

However, there isn't a bootstrap `.modal` method that allows for a callback.

Instead, you need to listen for the modal event `shown.bs.modal` before you show the modal, updated: code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#userModal').on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
      var name = 'brian';
      var user_id = 366; 
      $('#userModal .userName').val(name);
      $('#userModal .userId').val(user_id); 
  });
  $('#userModal').modal('show');
});
```